# How do I get a data.table with a specified formula for one column but also display the rest?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a `data.table` with an arbitrary number of columns but assume it's a lot.  I want to view the table where one column is transformed but the others are not.

Assuming the column I want to change is called `col1` and there are 100 columns, I want something like `DT[,list(col1=col1*2,.SD),.SDcols=2:100]`

I think this doesn't work because once I call `.SD` the scope changes (I'm not well versed in the under the hood stuff so I might have no idea what I'm talking about) and so it doesn't see `col1` anymore because I get `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'col1' not found`.
So assuming I only know the name of `col1` but I want the return to include all columns how do I do this.  Also, I don't want to change the original DT unless I absolutely have to.  (ie. I want to avoid `DT[,col1:=col1*2]`) if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the entire `data.table` but with one column modified, I'd simply use `copy`:

```
(copy(DT)[, col1 := col1*2])
```

And if you just want *some* columns - select first, then modify:

```
(DT[, 1:100][, col1 := col1*2])
```

Comment: at first I thought your first suggestion didn't work but then I actually ran it with the (not really) redundant outer parenthesis and it worked...thanks